# FPDF - failing to open eps file?

Tags: php, fpdf, adobe-illustrator, badge, eps

I am unable to use EPS file in FPDF (but here it is able to open EPS http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script84.php ). What is wrong in my code?

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: File was saved with wrong
>   Illustrator version: nato.eps in eps/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
>   eps/fpdf_eps.php(42): FPDF->Error('File was saved ...') #1
>   eps/test.php(7): PDF_EPS->ImageEps('test.eps', 30, 20, 150, 0, 1) #2
>   {main} thrown in eps/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271

**test.php:**

```
require('fpdf_eps.php');
$pdf=new PDF_EPS();
$pdf->AddPage();
$lnk = $pdf->AddLink();
$pdf->ImageEps('test.eps', 30, 20, 150, 0, $lnk);
$pdf->Output();
```

**fpdf_eps.php:**

```
/*
* Software: FPDF_EPS
* Version:  1.6
* Date:     2008-02-06
* Author:   Valentin Schmidt       */

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF_EPS extends FPDF{

function ImageEps ($file, $x, $y, $w=0, $h=0, $link='', $useBoundingBox=true){

    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($data===false) $this->Error('EPS file not found: '.$file);

    $regs = array();

    # EPS/AI compatibility check (only checks files created by Adobe Illustrator!)
    preg_match ('/%%Creator:([^\r\n]+)/', $data, $regs); # find Creator
    if (count($regs)>1){
        $version_str = trim($regs[1]); # e.g. "Adobe Illustrator(R) 8.0"
        if (strpos($version_str, 'Adobe Illustrator')!==false){
            $a = explode(' ', $version_str);
            $version = (float)array_pop($a);
            if ($version>=9)
                $this->Error('File was saved with wrong Illustrator version: '.$file);
                #return false; # wrong version, only 1.x, 3.x or 8.x are supported
        }#else
        #$this->Error('EPS wasn\'t created with Illustrator: '.$file);
    }

    # strip binary bytes in front of PS-header
    $start = strpos($data, '%!PS-Adobe');
    if ($start>0) $data = substr($data, $start);

    # find BoundingBox params
    preg_match ("/%%BoundingBox:([^\r\n]+)/", $data, $regs);
    if (count($regs)>1){
        list($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2) = explode(' ', trim($regs[1]));
    }
    else $this->Error('No BoundingBox found in EPS file: '.$file);

    $start = strpos($data, '%%EndSetup');
    if ($start===false) $start = strpos($data, '%%EndProlog');
    if ($start===false) $start = strpos($data, '%%BoundingBox');

    $data = substr($data, $start);

    $end = strpos($data, '%%PageTrailer');
    if ($end===false) $end = strpos($data, 'showpage');
    if ($end) $data = substr($data, 0, $end);

    # save the current graphic state
    $this->_out('q');

    $k = $this->k;

    if ($useBoundingBox){
        $dx = $x*$k-$x1;
        $dy = $y*$k-$y1;
    }else{
        $dx = $x*$k;
        $dy = $y*$k;
    }

    # translate
    $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F cm', 1,0,0,1,$dx,$dy+($this->hPt - 2*$y*$k - ($y2-$y1))));

    if ($w>0){
        $scale_x = $w/(($x2-$x1)/$k);
        if ($h>0){
            $scale_y = $h/(($y2-$y1)/$k);
        }else{
            $scale_y = $scale_x;
            $h = ($y2-$y1)/$k * $scale_y;
        }
    }else{
        if ($h>0){
            $scale_y = $h/(($y2-$y1)/$k);
            $scale_x = $scale_y;
            $w = ($x2-$x1)/$k * $scale_x;
        }else{
            $w = ($x2-$x1)/$k;
            $h = ($y2-$y1)/$k;
        }
    }

    # scale
    if (isset($scale_x))
        $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F %.3F cm', $scale_x,0,0,$scale_y, $x1*(1-$scale_x), $y2*(1-$scale_y)));

    # handle pc/unix/mac line endings
    $lines = preg_split ("/\r\n|[\r\n]/", $data);

    $u = 0;
    $cnt = count($lines);
    for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
        $line = $lines[$i];
        if ($line=='' || $line[0]=='%') continue;

        $len = strlen($line);

        $chunks = explode(' ', $line);
        $cmd = array_pop($chunks);

        # RGB
        if ($cmd=='Xa'||$cmd=='XA'){
            $b = array_pop($chunks); $g = array_pop($chunks); $r = array_pop($chunks);
            $this->_out("$r $g $b ". ($cmd=='Xa'?'rg':'RG') ); #substr($line, 0, -2).'rg' -> in EPS (AI8): c m y k r g b rg!
            continue;
        }

        switch ($cmd){
            case 'm':
            case 'l':
            case 'v':
            case 'y':
            case 'c':

            case 'k':
            case 'K':
            case 'g':
            case 'G':

            case 's':
            case 'S':

            case 'J':
            case 'j':
            case 'w':
            case 'M':
            case 'd' :

            case 'n' :
            case 'v' :
                $this->_out($line);
                break;

            case 'x': # custom fill color
                list($c,$m,$y,$k) = $chunks;
                $this->_out("$c $m $y $k k");
                break;

            case 'X': # custom stroke color
                list($c,$m,$y,$k) = $chunks;
                $this->_out("$c $m $y $k K");
                break;

            case 'Y':
            case 'N':
            case 'V':
            case 'L':
            case 'C':
                $line[$len-1] = strtolower($cmd);
                $this->_out($line);
                break;

            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                $this->_out($cmd . '*');
                break;

            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                if ($u>0){
                    $isU = false;
                    $max = min($i+5,$cnt);
                    for ($j=$i+1;$j<$max;$j++)
                        $isU = ($isU || ($lines[$j]=='U' || $lines[$j]=='*U'));
                    if ($isU) $this->_out("f*");
                }else
                    $this->_out("f*");
                break;

            case '*u':
                $u++;
                break;

            case '*U':
                $u--;
                break;

            #default: echo "$cmd<br>"; #just for debugging
        }

    }

    # restore previous graphic state
    $this->_out('Q');
    if ($link)
        $this->Link($x,$y,$w,$h,$link);

    return true;
}

}# END CLASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are confusing a script which specifically deals with EPS files created by Adobe Illustrator version 9, with a scritp which can handle general EPS files.

EPS stands for Encapsulated PostScript, PostScript is a programming language. So what is in an EPS file is a PostScript program.

Now machine generated PostScript, such as that produced by Adobe Illustrator, is of course always the same general format and its possible (as here) to write some code which can deal with its content in a limited fashion. However, the program generated by a different application will be different, possibly **very** different.

The only way to be able to read a general EPS (or PostScript file) is to use a full PostScript interpreter such as Ghostscript.

The script you have above is capable of reading **some** of the marking content of an  EPS generated by a specific version of Adobe Illustrator and rendering a PDF file from it, it is not a general PostScript interpreter and so is not capable of interpreting arbitrary EPS files. The author says as much in the page you linked to in your question.

> Only vector drawing is supported, not text or bitmap

Now notice that the exception is right at the beginning of the script where it checks the `%%Creator`comment to see if its the correct version of Illustrator. That's where it fails for you, undoubtedly because your EPS (which you haven't shared) doesn't include the correct comment.

In short you can't use this script to interpret general PostScript or EPS programs. If you want to do that you need something like Ghostscript or Adobe Acrobat Distiller.

Comment: That means .AI or .EPS files should be converted into .PDF (Ghostscript, AAD) and then use the .PDF in FPDF, TCPDF. Correct?

Comment: I can't really comment on using FPDF or TCPDF, I dn't use either of those tools. However .ai means its an Adobe Illustrator document, depending on the age of the Illustrator that can contain various things (a kind of PostScript or a kind of PDF). The only reliable thing that can open it is Adobe Illustrator. You can then export to PDF from Illustrator. Trying to use anything other than Illustrator **might** work, or might not. PostScript and EPS can be turned into PDF by Acrobat Distiller, Ghostscript and several other commercial products.

Comment: OK -  Thanks, i just used the same AI, EPS into PDF export. And then TCPDF, FPDF all works fine. The summary to my experience is that any AI or EPS file must be exported as PDF.